# How to enable http request / internet acces on samsung gear s2

Tags: javascript, httprequest, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I'm sending out http request on a toggle press on a web application for the gear s2 (javascript):

```
( function () {

    var led001Button = document.getElementById("Led001"),
        led002Button = document.getElementById("Led002");   

    function httpReq(theUrl){
        var xmlhttp = null;
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
//      if (xmlhttp.readyState == xmlhttp.DONE){
//      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
//      }
//      else{
//      alert(xmlhttp.statusText);
//      }
//      };
//      xmlhttp.onerror = function(e){
//      alert("onerror: " + xmlhttp.statusText);
//      };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function checkToggle(name){
            //make box2 = box1 when checked              
               var checkbox = document.getElementById(name);
               if (checkbox.checked === true){
                   httpReq('http://school.thomashuster.nl/WebServer/edit.php?name='+name+'&value=1');
//                console.log("set "+name+" ON");
               }else{
                   httpReq('http://school.thomashuster.nl/WebServer/edit.php?name='+name+'&value=0');
//                 console.log("set "+name+" OFF");
               }
    }           
    if (led001Button) {
        led001Button.addEventListener("change", function(){
               checkToggle("Led001");
        });
    }
    if (led002Button) {
        console.log('test');
        led002Button.addEventListener("change", function(){
               checkToggle("Led002");
        });
    }
} () );
```

When i emulate this on the gear s2 web emulator this works perfectly.

But when i install this on the gear s2 itself my webserver does not receive any requests. I gave my app Internet privilege and acces to my webserver in the config.xml file:

```
<access origin="https://www.thomashuster.nl" subdomains="true"></access>
 <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

but no succes. Can anybody tell me what i'm forgetting? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your code is not accessing from any other domain?
Can you try with modifying the access origin in config.xml to <access origin="*" subdomains="true">

Comment: please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your code is not accessing from any other domain?

If its accessing from other domains then you need to modify the access origin in config.xml to

`<access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>` 
or

`<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`